# Delete cells and columns based on a cell entry

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete cells in specific columns.

```
Sub do_it()

    Dim sht As Worksheet, n As String, cell, num, tmp, rngDest As Range, i As Integer
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    n = sht.Range("A1").Value
    i = 0
    For Each cell In sht.Range("A20:A34,D20:D34,H20:H34").Cells
        tmp = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then
            'get the first number
            num = CLng(Trim(Split(tmp, "-")(0)))

            'find the next empty cell in the appropriate    row
            Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)

            'make sure not to add before col J
            If rngDest.Column < 12 Then Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, 12)
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Copy rngDest

            ' This is getting the next number in A/D/H----
            Set tmp = cell.Offset(1, 0)

            ' This is filling up B17 - F18 in order until filled
            If sht.Range("B17").Value = "" Then
                sht.Range("C17").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                sht.Range("B17").Value = tmp.Value
            ElseIf sht.Range("C18").Value = "" Then
                sht.Range("C18").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                sht.Range("B18").Value = tmp.Value
            ElseIf sht.Range("E17").Value = "" Then
                sht.Range("E17").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                sht.Range("D17").Value = tmp.Value
            ElseIf sht.Range("E18").Value = "" Then
                sht.Range("E18").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                sht.Range("D18").Value = tmp.Value
            End If

            '---- This clears the B columns  after using the value ----
            Dim rg As Range, rg1 As Range
            If cell.Column = 1 Then
                Set rg = cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1)
                If cell.Column > 1 Then Set rg1 = cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then rg.ClearContents  'will be delete column b
    'If Not rg1 Is Nothing Then  rg1.ClearContents 'will be delete column e,f,g,
End Sub
```

The issue is deleting the correct column after the copy and paste process.

Using the Excel image:

When a number entered in cell A1 (8 in this case) is found in the cell range A20:A34 (cell B34), in only this cell range do I need the contents of cell B34 to be deleted after being copied and pasted.

When the number is found in cell ranges D20:D34 and H20:H34, I need cells E20/F20/G20 AND I/J/K to be deleted after the copy and paste function is done.

Excel sheet:
[image]

Comment: `Dim sht As Worksheet,  n As String,    cell,  num,  tmp,  rngDest As Range` declares `rngDest` as `Range` but `cell,num, tmp` as `Variant`. Was that your intention?

Comment: It works but can I ask what the issue is. I'm getting there but my VBA experience isn't anywhere yours.  Thank-you for your help.

Comment: I just checked and this my original;                                    Sub do_it()
    Dim n, sht As Worksheet, cell As Range, num, tmp, rngDest As Range
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    n = sht.Range("A1")
    For Each cell In sht.Range("A15:A30,C15:C30,E15:E30,G15:G30,I15:I30").Cells
       tmp = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If cell.Value = n And tmp Like "*#-#*" Then
            'get the first number
            num = CLng(Trim(Split(tmp, "-")(0)))
            Debug.Print "Found a positive result in " & cell.Address

Comment: The rest;                                                                                    'find the next empty cell in the appropriate row
         Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
            'make sure not to add before col L
            If rngDest.Column < 12 Then Set rngDest = sht.Cells(num, 12)
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Copy rngDest
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on board!

In order to achieve this:

> When a number entered in cell A1 (8 in this case) is found in the cell
>   range A20:A34 (cell B34), in only this cell range, do I need the
>   contents of cell B34 to be deleted after being copied and pasted.
>
> When the number is found in cell ranges D20:D34 and H20:H34, I need
>   cells E20/F20/G20 AND I/J/K to be deleted after the copy and paste
>   function is done.

You need to replace this part of your code:

```
        Dim rg As Range, rg1 As Range
        If cell.Column = 1 Then
            Set rg = cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1)
            If cell.Column > 1 Then Set rg1 = cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2)
        End If
```

With this:

```
        Select Case cell.Column
        Case 1 'If found in column A, delete the next cell
            cell.Offset(, 1).ClearContents
        Case 4, 8 'If found in column D or H, delete cells E20/F20/G20 AND I/J/K
            Range("D20:D34,H20:H34,I:I,J:J,K:K").ClearContents
        End Select
```